# MYSQL BEFORE INSERT trigger does not insert record into table

Tags: mysql, database, algorithm, database-design, triggers

I am using MYSQL 5.7.19 on ubuntu 16.04 (local mashine). I have 2 tables schema:

```
CREATE TABLE raw (rdate DATE, pim int(3));
CREATE TABLE indx (idate DATE, ipim int(2));
INSERT INTO raw (rdate, pim)
VALUES (20000101,50), (20000201, 52);
INSERT INTO indx (idate, ipim)
VALUES (20000101,5), (20000201, 5);
```

Table `raw` is for monthly data `date` and `pim` numbers. I want to write the `trigger - before insert` which will compare new `pim` with latest (is new `pim` higher or lower compared to previous `pim` value) and then according to number ranges (for example: if `pim` is between 40 and 50 than `ipim` = 5) insert particular number into column `ipim` in table `indx` and the new `rdate` into new `idate`.
Here is my trigger code:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER sortpim BEFORE INSERT ON raw
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
DECLARE new_pim,old_pim,max_d INT;
SET new_pim = NEW.pim;
SET old_pim = (SELECT pim FROM raw WHERE rdate > CURDATE());
  IF (old_pim <= new_pim) THEN
    CASE WHEN new_pim BETWEEN 50 AND 59 THEN
        INSERT INTO indx(idate,ipim) VALUES(NEW.rdate,6);
      WHEN new_pim BETWEEN 60 AND 70 THEN
        INSERT INTO indx(idate,ipim) VALUES(NEW.rdate,7);
    END CASE;
  ELSEIF (old_pim > new_pim) THEN
    CASE
      WHEN new_pim BETWEEN 50 AND 60 THEN
        INSERT INTO indx(idate,ipim) VALUES(NEW.rdate,5);
      WHEN new_pim BETWEEN 40 AND 49 THEN
        INSERT INTO indx(idate,ipim) VALUES(NEW.rdate,4);
    END CASE;
  END IF;
END; //
DELIMITER ;
```

The trigger code is accepted with no errors but when I try to trigger it by inserting new record into `raw` table:

`INSERT INTO raw(rdate,pim) VALUES(20000301,55);`

record is inserted with no errors and the trigger does not do anything - the `indx` table is not inserted with new record.

I'm new in MYSQL thus it is likely I choose wrong logic or methods. And it could be mistakes in algorithm or syntax. Any suggestions to solve this is appreciated. Thanx.

UPDATE!
Thanx for suggestions and point where are my mistake.
I have found the solution for getting the latest date as there was the mistake in trigger code on line 7. Here is what works:

```
` SELECT pim FROM raw ORDER BY rdate DESC LIMIT 1; `
```

Comment: Will this `SELECT pim FROM raw WHERE rdate > CURDATE()` ever return anything?

Comment: Same question?? And if it will then obviously it will return more than one row.

Comment: No. Just tried to run it on mysql terminal: ` mysql> SELECT pim FROM raw WHERE rdate > CURDATE();
Empty set (0.00 sec) `. I have tried `SELECT pim FROM raw WHERE MAX(rdate);` but it gives ERROR 1111 Invalid use of group function.

Comment: Then that's your issue. If `old_pim` gets no value, then it can't compare to `new_pim` and just falls through the logic.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I found the easy way to get latest record: `SELECT pim FROM raw ORDER BY rdate DESC LIMIT 1;` .